# Stop wifi beacon when idle

Tags: linux, wifi, hostapd

I can't believe no one ever did this, but I'm searching for days now and haven't found anything.

I have just bought a Raspberry Pi 4 and would like to use it as a wifi access point (for information, I will probably install Gentoo with *hostapd* in it).

I would like this access point to be in “passive” mode, only listening to new devices and not emitting beacon when there is no station connected to it. I looked at *hostapd* configuration file, but I could not find anything suitable.

I wonder if I can, by order of preference:

- find a configuration option to manage this automatically;
- be able to automatically capture connection/disconnection events and switch beacon on/off using a bit of shell scripting;
- if nothing else is available, modify a driver or an application to add this no beacon idle mode.

Have someone ever heard of a way to do this?